# ionic: missing entitlements for iOS project

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed ionic application with following environment. Now, I need to transfer the work to my colleague but he is unable to build fully functional app which includes capabilities such as 'Associated domains', 'Background Modes' and 'Push Notifications'.

`cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
    Node              : v10.8.0
    npm               : 6.2.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000`

Although he is able to build and archive the project, generated ipa has no entitlements listed(all of them are ON at capability selections) and Certificate says "Unknown" at the export dialog using Organizer.

We are using the same certificates, profiles and everything but the OS.
I am using macOS High Sierra with Xcode 9.4.1 and he is using macOS mojave and Xcode 10.1.

Our Android version of app can be build and run fine.

Does anyone have similar experience and know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We found [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110438) on apple developer forum and by downgrading Xcode, the build problem was resolved.

Old version of Xcode can be downloaded [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).